# iPhone simulator in Visual Studio 2019: "Device { } not found."

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2019, ios-simulator

I am running VS 2019 vs. 16.9.4.  I have a Xamarin.Forms project and am trying to build & deploy to an iPhone simulator.  I can connect to the mac and all seems ok on that end.  When I try to start the app for the simulator I get a small window titled "iOS Simulator" which says "Connected", and then changes to "Waiting for device...", and then another small window pops up titled "Xamarin Simulator" which says "The device {GUID here} was not found."

I get this same series of messages regardless of which iPhone simulator I choose.

I have both XCode and Visual Studio 2019 for Mac running on the Mac.

What am I missing?

Comment: First, have you successfully built on the Mac itself using VS Mac, and run that on the emulator without a problem? To make sure everything is correct on the mac side.

Comment: Second, there is an option on vs on pc (options / xamarin / ..) that controls whether the simulated image is remoted back to the pc, or displayed on the mac. To try to get this to work one way or the other, if that option is on, turn it off. Or if it is off, turn it on. Save, and quit visual studio. Reboot both mac and pc. Test.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions.   If I uncheck the option to remote the simulator then it works fine on the Mac - it opens a simulator on the Mac, starts up, and runs the app.  Takes a horribly long time to get it up and running the first time, but eventually all works fine.  But if I try to remote it to thr PC, so I can run the simulator on my Windows dev machine, I get the error described above.

Comment: Hmm.  I was hoping that after you ran it once on the Mac, so that it would download whatever was needed (that horribly long first time), it would work if you switched back to showing on WIndows. Sorry, I've never seen that error before. For me, after I made sure it was working on Mac, I was able to change the setting, reboot both mac and pc, and then it worked on pc.

Comment: Update:  if I target iOS version 14.5, I get the error described above.  Any previous versions (I have 13.0 through 14.5 installed) do pop up a simulator window, but it is entirely black and none of the buttons work.  The simulator does not finish loading or launch the app.

Comment: OK. Maybe a bug in 14.5 support. Lets try to get one of the others, with a black window, to work. This is a common problem. Again, get the chosen version to first work on Mac directly. Then, try [my fix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54728377/199364). If that doesn't help, look at the other answers there. Or google for similar threads at stackoverflow or xamarin forums - there should be several. In fact there was one at stackoverflow a week or so ago, IIRC.

Answer (score 1):

Today I updated Visual Studio to 16.9.5.
The Xamarin.iOS was updates to 14.16.0.5 in Mac hardware.
But the remote iOS Simulator still not working.

In Options > Xamarin > iOS Settings I unchecked the Remote Simulator to Windows.
Now I managed use the iOS Simulator in Mac hardware through VNC

It's not the dream solution, but works.

Comment: Have you tried XCode 13 yet? This bug is supposedly been fixed in VS 2019 v16.11 (see [bug report](https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/t/VS-2019-1694-cannot-connect-to-iOS-Sim/1412563)). I will give it a shot later today.

Answer (score 1):

Iphone simulator working in Visual Studio 2019 version 16.10.4 on windows machine.

Answer (score 1):

It's finally fixed! The remote iOS simulator finally works in **VS 2019 16.11.5** and **XCode 13.1**.

Comment: Just tested in VS 2022 v17.0 and it works there too.